# When equating a rational function to zero, is there anything to be done with the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, rational-functions

> I am solving this equation: 
>   $$0 = \frac{2x-20-y}{30-2y+x}$$

I'm pretty sure that for this to equal zero I just need to solve the numerator, but is there anything I need to do with the denominator?

EDIT: i need a numerical value for x and y

Answer (score 1):

The numerator must be $0$ and the denominator must not. So the solution is 
$$y=2x-20,x\neq \frac{70}3$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice $$0=\frac{2x-20-y}{30-2y+x}$$ $$\implies 30-2y+x\ne 0\tag 1$$
$$\implies 2x-20-y=0\tag 2$$
substituting $y=2x-20$ from (2) into (1), we get $$30-2(2x-20)+x\neq 0$$
$$x\ne \frac{70}{3}$$

Hence the solution is $$x\ne \frac{70}{3}$$
& $$y=2x-20$$

Comment: But i need numerical values for x and y, not what you have given

Comment: @Lily There are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Values ? There are infinite solutions satisfying the above two conditions.